# Impersonation Step that's dependent on an IF condition

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, impersonation, conditional

I'm writing a workflow for a dispatch process in a warehouse. The item goes through several stages before it can be closed, and at each stage, the item must be edited by different groups.

I'm thinking the best way to do this is using impersonation steps, changing the permissions at each of the stages of the process to give appropriate access to the relevant group, and preventing certain people from editing the item.

My question is, is it possible to have an IF statement prior to an impersonation step? So, for example:

`IF 'document status' equals 'pending'<br>
--- [Admin] has full control<br>
--- [Finance] has read<br>
--- [Security] has contribute`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Impersonation Step has to be its own block and so you need to put the If statement inside the impersonation step (and not the other way around).

Only the SP2010 Workflow Engine has the Activities required to change the item's permission configuration but you can, if you want to follow the 2013 engine route, create a web service that's responsible for doing the work of configuring the proper permissions.